# R Output of fGarch

Tags: r, time-series, fgarch

I am modelling a time series as a GARCH(1,1)-process:

[image: Garch]

And the z_t are t-distributed.

In R, I do this in the `fGarch`-package via

```
model <- garchFit(formula = ~garch(1,1), cond.dist = "std", data=r)
```

Is this correct?

Now, I would like to understand the output of this to check my formula.

Obviously, `model@fit$coefs` gives me the coefficients and `model@fitted` gives me the fitted r_t.

But how do I get the fitted sigma_t and z_t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best way is to define extractor functions when generics are not available and methods when generics already exist.

The first two functions extract the values of interest from the fitted objects.

```
get_sigma_t <- function(x, ...){
  x@sigma.t
}
get_z_t <- function(x, ...){
  x@fit$series$z
}
```

Here a `logLik` method for objects of class `"fGARCH"` is defined.

```
logLik.fGARCH <- function(x, ...){
  x@fit$value
}
```

Now use the functions, including the method. The data comes from the first example in `help("garchFit")`.

```
N <- 200
r <- as.vector(garchSim(garchSpec(rseed = 1985), n = N)[,1])
model <- garchFit(~ garch(1, 1), data = r, trace = FALSE)

get_sigma_t(model) # output not shown
get_z_t(model)     # output not shown

logLik(model)
#LogLikelihood 
#    -861.9494
```

Note also that methods `coef` and `fitted` exist, there is no need for `model@fitted` or `model@fit$coefs`, like is written in the question.

```
fitted(model)  # much simpler
coef(model)
#          mu        omega       alpha1        beta1 
#3.541769e-05 1.081941e-06 8.885493e-02 8.120038e-01
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that I don't know which is which. If I add up the z_t and the sigma_t from what fGarch gives me, I don't arrive at the fitted r_t

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo `sigma.t` is the conditional sd, why add to `z`?

Comment: In the model we have `r_t = mu + z_t * sigma_t` - Now `sigma_t` is obviously `sigma.t` but where do I find `z_t`in the model output?

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo `e <- residuals(model); z <- e/sigma.t`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a `list` structure.  Can find the structure with

```
str(model)
```

From the structure, it is easier to extract with `$` or `@`

```
model@fit$series$z
model@sigma.t
```

Comment: So model@sigma_t gives me the sigma_t in above model specification? I am trying to make sure that the model and I are talking about the same objects... also how can I get z_t in the fitted model?

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo I don't find an object named `z_t`.  I thought it is the `z` from the 'series'

Comment: The problem is that if I add up the z_t and sigma_t according to the model formula, I don't arrive at the true value

Comment: @ClaudioMoneo I am not that familiar with the garch model